# list has not been declared

Tags: c++, lista

Estou realizando a primeira parte de um trabalho em c++ no codeblocks e ubuntu e estou obtendo os seguintes erros:

> 1 - 'list' has not been declared
>   2 - no matching function for call
>   to 'No::verificaExisteNo(int&, std::list&)'

Existe o include nos cabeçalhos e não entendi o que possa ser esse segundo erro.

No.h:

```
#ifndef NO_H
#define NO_H
#include <list>

class No{
    int id; //id do nó

    public:
    No(int);
    bool verificaExisteNo(int id, list &listNos);
};

#endif // NO_H
```

No.cpp:

```
#include "No.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

No::No(int id){
    this->id=id;
}

bool No::verificaExisteNo(int id,list &listNos){
    //para teste sempre retorno true;
    return true;
}
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>
#include "No.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int opcao,id1;
    No *noAux;

    list<No> listNos;
    list<No> listAdj;
    list<No>::iterator it;

    do{
    cout << "Trabalho de Teoria dos Grafos - 2016.1 - Eduardo Machado Lopes - 201465583A\n\nEscolha uma opcao para comecar:\n0 - Carregar arquivo do grafo."
        "\n1 - Incluir no.\n2 - Excluir no.\n3 - Incluir aresta.\n4 - Remover aresta.\n5 - Consultar no do grau.\n6 - Verifica k-regularidade.\n"
        "7 - Verifica se e completo.\n8 - Verifica se sao adjacentes.\n9 - Verifica se e conexo.\n10 - Verifica se pertencem a mesma componente conexa.\n"
        "11 - Verifica se e articulacao.\n12 - Verifica se e ponte.\n13 - Exibir lista de nos.\n14 - Exibir arestas.\n15 - Sair.\n\nEscolha: ";
    cin >> opcao;
    system("clear");
        switch (opcao){
            case 0:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 1:
                cout << "Informe o nó que deseja inserir: ";
                cin >> id1;
                //Primeiro verifico se ele existe;
                if(noAux->verificaExisteNo(id1,listNos))
                    cout << "Existe nó";
                else
                    cout << "No existe nó";
            break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 3:cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 5:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 6:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 7:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 8:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 9:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 10:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 11:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 12:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 13:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
            case 14:
                cout << "Em construcao.\n";
            break;
        }
        cout << endl;
    } while (opcao!=15);
    return 0;
}
```

Agradeço de qualquer forma!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você esqueceu de colocar o `namespace` em `No.h`. E nos arquivos `No.h` e `No.cpp` você deve definir o tipo da lista `list<No>`

```
#ifndef NO_H
#define NO_H
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class No{
    int id; //id do nó

    public:
    No(int);
    bool verificaExisteNo(int id, list<No> listNos);
};

#endif // NO_H
```

Sem o `namespace` você pode declarar a `list` com o `std::list`:

```
bool verificaExisteNo(int id, std::list<No> listNos);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Brumazzi, porém agora o erro que está aparecendo é: 'list' is not a type...

Comment: tem como mandar a alteração que vc fez para chegar nesse erro?

Comment: Coloquei como outra resposta para poder manter a identação @Brumazzi DB...

Comment: @DuduLopes fiz uma alteração na resposta, ve se agora funciona, no meu pc funcionou

Comment: Funcionou! Preciso editar o titulo para resolvido?

Comment: não, só tendo o **v** marcado já indica que seu problema foi resolvido